# Vim, netrw plugin tmp files not uploaded at server

Tags: vim

If I connect via sftp with netrw plugin and open the file, filepath looks like `sftp://..` In current session if I close this file and reopen it, netrw loads file from `/tmp/..` and after saving this file is not uploaded to server. How can I delete temp file after closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it did not turn out to win, but I found one alternative - it's buffers. For convenience and easy access, I use a plugin [bufexplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42) and the second time I open the file directly from it already.